# How to learn using content repository and Apache JackRabbit?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jackrabbit, content-repository

Where do I go after doing the "First hops" in the Apache JackRabbit website? I don't understand how to create a repository that is not in memory and how to configure it and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look also at [Silverpeas](http://www.silverpeas.org) code.
It's using Jackrabbit with some simple code to create nodes, browse them etc. For example take a look into https://github.com/Silverpeas/Silverpeas-Core/blob/master/lib-core/src/main/java/org/silverpeas/attachment/repository/DocumentRepository.java
The tests are using in memory repository but the final stuff is using a 'real' repository.

Also you might take a look at [JBoss Modeshape](http://www.jboss.org/modeshape) which is another implementation of the JCR API. Some of the docs are cross implementation.
There is also [Crash](http://www.crashub.org/) which enables you to add a shell to your running repository.

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to my world. The Jackrabbit documentation is a bit all over the place. you will have to do some serious googling.

However the [Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/FrontPage) is a good place to start. Start with the [Examples page](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/ExamplesPage). Just try to add a new record into the CMS. Then implement versioning. Don't worry about embedding it yet into an application. I would use the standalone version at this stage.

If you're up to it, you can also download the [Apache Sling](http://sling.apache.org/) source codes. Look through the JCR packages. You'll get a few tips on how to use it in a Web application.

Comment: Okey, so it isn't only me who struggles with getting a grip on it. I am not going to use Apache Sling though, but is it still a good place to learn? What did you do after going through the example page and wiki?