# Actual Jackrabbit/Oak guides and documentation

Tags: java, jcr, jackrabbit, content-repository

I need to implement file storage with directories and some metadata in my Spring MVC application for binary files (mostly *.pdf, sometimes *.doc, *.pptx, images). There are some thousands of them. Total volume 15 or more gigabytes. Storing them in SQL database is also required. All of it runs on WildFly. 
As i see JCR specification perfictly fits my needs. It seems that Jackrabbit is the only actual implementation of JCR specification. For example the last ModeShape release (known alternative) on maven was on 2017 and it seems dead.

The problem is in documentation and examples. Despite to frequent updates of Jackrabbit and Jackrabbit Oak most links from google and even on official site outdated, 6-10 years old, or leads nowhere.

I' ve found similar question [How to learn using content repository and Apache JackRabbit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783838/how-to-learn-using-content-repository-and-apache-jackrabbit) , but wiki links on 
https://cwiki.apache.org 
are broken now. I couldn`t find anything there about Jackrabbit. The only tutorial about Jackrabbit and database integration i found is this: https://dzone.com/articles/creating-a-content-repository-using-jackrabbit-oak

So questions:
1. What is current state of JCR and Jackrabbit/Oak. Are they abandoned?
2. Is there up to date alternatives, that fits my needs (Spring, SQL, file structure for storing binary files) ?
3. What happened to Jackrabbit wiki, and how to find information about Jackrabbit?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classic Jackrabbit is mostly in maintenance mode. Jackrabbit Oak is actively developed.

The Jackrabbit Wiki was not maintained for a long time, and now has been archived (due to a Wiki platform change in the Apache infrastructure).

Current Jackrabbit/Oak documentation is over here: https://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/index.html

If you have a concrete question I would recommend to ask on the Jackrabbit user mailing list.

Comment: I can't help with Spring. WRT SQL storage, please see the documentation for DocumentNodeStore in general, and RDBDocumentStore specifically.